# How to merge MP3s folder based an automatically keep all ID3v2.1/3 tags and pictire (all properties that match in all files)?

Tags: audio, mp3, id3, merge

I've a bunch of audiobooks. Each in one folder, separated into multiple files. I want to make one audiobook into one file (that works better for cheap mp3 players). I want to keep all ID3-Tag information, that is the same in every file (for example the title, alblum, year, picture, etc.).

I know I can join some files using ffmpeg. But there are so many parameters and I don't know which to use. Is there an easier way? May be with a GUI? Or a good plugin for an music player I did not found yet?

Comment: I've used some free components (non commercial use) from https://www.3delite.hu/ now and builded my own delphi app. May be I can publish this on GitHub if there is any interest.

Comment: Fyi - there are also GUIs for ffmpeg like https://qwinff.github.io/ https://github.com/WinFF/winff